# How to get primary key with Spring JdbcTemplate after SQL update?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

This returns null:

```
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbc.update((Connection connection) -> {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setString(1, entity.getStatus().toString());
        ps.setLong(2, entity.getItemId());
        return ps;

    }, keyHolder);
return keyHolder.getKey();
```

Here is the SQL:

```
UPDATE jobs SET status=? WHERE item_id=?
```

On an sql insert this will return the auto generated primary key. But if I am updating, is there a way to get the primary keys of the updated rows?

**Edited**

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not sure about spring jdbc template but jdbc generally returns the number of rows updated.

Comment: are you updating a single row or a batch?

Comment: Returing generated key also depend on JDBC driver. Please offer the information about JDBC driver(type, version...)

Comment: I added the MySQL connector dependency up top. The update should only update a single row, but that can't be guaranteed.

Comment: Assuming item_id is not the primary key, you should go with batchUpdate() rather than update as you said it could possibly affect multiple rows. In such case I do not see springJDBCTemplate having any update call returning a list of primary keys of updated rows. You might have to write something manual.